# How do I clear a keyEquivalent for a NSButton?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How do I clear a keyEquivalent for a NSButton ?

I've tried:

```
[theButton setKeyEquivalent:nil];
```

but it doesn't seem to be correct!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you're looking for is:

```
[theButton setKeyEquivalent:@""];
```